# NSFetchedResultsController predicate to eliminate duplicates of several properties

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController in my UITableViewController.

Is it possible to specify a predicate that will not retrieve items which have duplicate fields in x number of fields that I specify.

For example, I want to search all results for items but if the itemName AND itemDescription AND itemQuantity are the same, I want only one of these items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

When the page loads do a single run through the data and keep a list of objectID that are duplicate. For duplicate object set the row height of the cell to be 0.  So they are technically still there, but you can't see it.  This make dealing with the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate calls easy because no indexPaths have changed

### Option 2

If the dataset is always selected in the same way and an object that is a duplicate is always a duplicate you can set an 'isDuplicate' in the object and filter it out in the predicate.  Or you can not store at all in the first place. If objects are displayed in different sets and in different way and sometime should be displayed and sometime not be displayed this is not a good solution

### Option 3

If you are sorting by the same criteria that make an object duplicate (that is duplicates always appear right next to a non-duplicate) and you are NOT using sections, then you can use sectionKeyPath.  SectionKeyPath groups items together into sections.  Group the duplicate and non duplicate together and then display every section as a single row (use the first item in each section).  The indexPaths of the fetchedResultsController will not match the indexPaths of the tableview so you have to careful to convert them.

### Option 4

Instead of accessing the objects from a fetchedResultsController do a fetch and and filter the array.  Then use the array to display the objects.  The downside is that you don't get updates on when objects change.  This can be especially problematic is objects are deleted, as accessing a managedObject that's entity was delete can lead to a crash.

I recommend option 1